# Iterating through a for loop

Tags: python, loops

I am looking for that the input is in the list and gives me an answer or it is not in the list and states "not found"

```
contacts = [
    ('James', 42),
    ('Amy', 24),
    ('John', 31),
    ('Amanda', 63),
    ('Bob', 18)
]

name = input()

for x in contacts:
    if name == x[0]: 
        print("%s is %d" % (x[0], x[1]))
        break
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

But my answer always comes out like this for Amanda:

```
Not Found
Not Found
Not Found
Amanda is 63
```

How do I get ride of the three "Not Found" and why?

Comment: You cannot know whether it was not found when you have not yet finished the loop. That message should not be printed in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: De-indent the else block to the `for` loop level.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop at all. `if any((witness:=x)[0] == name for x in contacts): print(f'{witness[0]} is {witness[1]}') else: print("Not found")`.

Comment: can you explain this solution @chepner

Comment: `any` returns true if any of the comparisons succeeds, notably stopping at the first such success. The assignment expression captures the value of `x` that made `any` return true.

Answer (score 2):

In your loop, there will be a `print` executed in *every* iteration -- either in the `if` case, or in the `else` case.

But printing "not found" in the first iteration is premature. At that moment you cannot know whether the name is in the list or not, as you have not inspected all entries yet. So this should not be printed while the loop is still looping. It should be printed when the loop has finished.

So make the `else` a clause that acts on the `for` statement, not on the `if` statement:

```
for x in contacts:
    if name == x[0]: 
        print(str(x[0]) + " is " + str(x[1]))
        break
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

The `else` block now only executes when the `for` loop completed all iterations without executing `break`.

---

Not your question, but this code can be made a bit more elegant:

- You can unpack the contact entry into its name and age parts
- You can use an f-string for printing

```
for contact, age in contacts:
    if name == contact: 
        print(f"{contact} is {age}")
        break
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

And if you want, you could use comprehension and call `next` with its default argument:

```
print(next((f"{contact} is {age}" 
            for contact, age in contacts if name == contact
           ), "Not Found"))
```

Comment: It should be noted that `else` block for `for` loop is only executed if loop finished normally, i.e. without using `break`. That's why it is not printed if the name was found.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written works exactly as expected. Logically it is looking at the first item and finding that it does not match the string "Amanda" so it prints "Not found". Then it does the same for the next two. In order to have this not be the behavior you need to check if you are at the last index and you have previously not found whatever input.

```
found = False


for x in contacts:
    if name == x[0]: 
        print(str(x[0]) + " is " + str(x[1]))
        found = True
        break



if(not found):
    print("Not Found")
```

Comment: I honestly don't know if bang operators work in python I coded this in stack overflow I will check later

Comment: Because it doesn't work. Python booleans use capital letter (`False`, `True`) and logical NOT is `not`, not `!`

Comment: I forgot this @matszwecja